# show and hide Javascript (display:none) issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a show/hide javascript function which seems to work perfectly - When you click on the link it reveals the gif version of the logo.

The issue i'm having is when you first go onto the landing page [click here](http://iamnatesmithen.com/jukebox/index2.html) you can see both images, it's only when you click on the still image the function works the way is should - only displaying one image at a time. Does anyone know how i can resolve this problem?

Comment: You should add 'display:none' in the css on the image you want to hide on load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to give the image a `display:none` style as well to start with:

```
<img id="center-img-gif" alt="main-img" src="css/images/logo.gif" style="display:none;">
```

Answer (score 0):

use CSS property `Display:none;` for one of the images.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `display:none` of one image at design time
OR
You can set `display:none` of one image on `body onload`